# How to highlight a dropdown menu in navbar when a site within the dropdown is selected using bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, dropdown, bootstrap-5, navbar

I have a navbar component with links to regular pages, and dropdowns that link to multiple pages.
When the regular page is selected and the user is taken to that page, the navbar component remains highlighted.["About" is highlighted when user is on the about page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJIjA.png)

If I am in my dropdown part of the navbar and select a page from there, while the dropdown is showing, the main part of the dropdown is highlighted ("Help" is in white). [Help dropdown with a section selected in the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rou14.png)

When I click out of the dropdown to get rid of it, the dropdown loses its highlight ("Help" is now gray) even if I am in a page that is listed under the dropdown. [grayed out "Help" dropdown section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKMVh.png)

I would like the main text of the dropdown be highlighted when I am in a page that is listed under the dropdowns even if the dropdown is not open. (i.e. when I am in the general methodology page, I want "Help" to be in white even if the dropdown selection is hidden).

Here is my code as it stands:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/site">Site name</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarMenu" aria-controls="navbarMenu"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li *ngIf="showAdmin" class="nav-item"><a
                    class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Home</a></li>
                <li *ngIf="showAdmin" class="nav-item"><a
                    class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">About</a></li>
                <li *ngIf="showAdmin" ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown"><a
                    class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                      [routerLinkActive]="['active']" ngbDropdownToggle>Help</a>
                    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
                        aria-labelledby="dropdown-help">
                        <a ngbDropdownItem class="dropdown-item"
                            routerLink="/help/general" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">General
                            methodology</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a ngbDropdownItem class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/help/site"
                            [routerLinkActive]="['active']" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">tutorial</a> 
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    </div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I am using html, css, and Typescript.